# Problema a la hora de agregar un valor a un map

Tags: api, flutter, dart

Hola estoy tratando de agregar un valor que lo tengo en una lista dinamica

_events es un Map<DateTime, List> que es una variable,
_controller es una variablde CalendarController que es una libreria de Callendar flluter
TurnModelGetAllBEmployeeId, es donde recibo todos los turnos agendados que tengo y es una lista dinamica. Ya intente con turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId[0][dateTime], turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId[0]['dateTime'], el error que me aparece es el siguiente (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null. supongo que es porque estoy accediendo mal a la propiedad

porcion del codigo donde creo e inicializo _controller y _events

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = CalendarController();
    _events = {};
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = Provider.of(context);
    userModel = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Usuario: ${bloc.userName} home page'),
          centerTitle: true),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            TableCalendar(
              locale: 'en_US',
              events: _events,
              calendarController: _controller,
```

aqui es donde hago toda la logica para poder agregar el dia en el que el paciente tiene el turno,

```
 if (picked != null) {
      turnPorivder.createTurn(turnModel);
       }
       _events[_controller.selectedDay]
      .add(turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId[0].dateTime); //el error lo tengo aqui
```

El problema lo estoy teniendo en _events[_controller.selectedDay] es null y no se porque, estoy utilizando un tutorial como guia

Comment: _events[_controller.selectedDay] es null

Comment: ambos estan inicializados events como {} y controller como CallendarController en el initState `  Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> _events;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = CalendarController();
    _events = {};`

Comment: haz un print de `_events[_controller.selectedDay] `  antes del .add

Comment: tenes razon diego esta null, como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: agrega el código como inicializas eso, ahí está el error

Comment: Estoy siguiendo un tutorial en youtube de como utilizar la libreria, y no la inicializa en ningun lado,te muestro la porcion de codigo en donde hago lo que el hace
  if (_eventController.text.isEmpty) return;
                    if (_events[_controller.selectedDay] != null) {
                      _events[_controller.selectedDay]
                          .add(_eventController.text);
                    } else {
                      _events[_controller.selectedDay] = [
                        _eventController.text
                      ];
                    }

Comment: digo que actualices la pregunta con el código para poder apreciarlo mejor, no en el comment,  revisa donde agrega la información

Comment: _events = {}; está vacío , donde lo llenas de datos?

Comment: Ya pude verlo diego, mi error pero algo estoy pensado/haciendo mal y no se que es te agradezco por la ayuda

Comment: dale, de nada , te invito a mi canal : www.youtube.com/diegoveloper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente map no tiene la [funcion add](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/Map-class.html)

La manera correcta de asociar un valor a una llave es esta

```
miMapa[mivalor]=miValorAsociado;
```

en tu caso sería

```
_events[_controller.selectedDay] = turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId[0].dateTime;
```

Comment: Hola, si ciertamente tenes razon pero aparte de agregar el DateTime tenia que agregar otro valor y no sabia como hacerlo, la forma en lo que resolvi fue asi    Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> data = {};
    turns[0].forEach((element) {
      DateTime date = DateTime.tryParse(element['dateTime']);
      if (data[date] == null) data[date] = [];
      data[date].add(turns);
    });
    return data;
Te agradezco por haberte tomado tu tiempo de responderme :D

Answer (score 0):

La forma como lo resolvi fue la siguiente, creo una funcion por parametro la cual recibe una lista dynamic(porque tiene distintos valores) luego creo un mapa, recorro el parametro enviado y le agrego el DateTime y retorno otro map con el dateTime y la lista

```
  Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> data = {};
    turns[0].forEach((element) {
      DateTime date = DateTime.tryParse(element['dateTime']);
      if (data[date] == null) data[date] = [];
      data[date].add(turns);
    });
    return data;
```